# newly added picklist values in (case) status field not available for selection,

Tags: configuration

I have added the values(Success,Failed etc.) in Status field and also added these new values in Support process which is used by a record type.
when i create new case record using that record type ,i am not getting new Status values for selection.Am i missing Something

Comment: Does your org have custom record types for the `Case` object? Have you gone into Setup -> Customize -> Cases -> Record Types and explicitly added the new picklist options for each record type?

Comment: Hi @DerekF ,i face this issue with Standard status field of case which is controlled by support process and i don't see status values while editing picklist values in RecordTypes.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the value(s) to your Support Process (Classic: Setup > Customize > Cases > Support Processes, Lightning: Setup > Feature Settings > Service > Support Processes).

Comment: I have added these values in support process already but its not available for selection

Comment: @PrabhatJha Is it a closed value? Do you allow closing on the edit page?

Comment: No .values are success,failed,closed-unresolved etc..

Comment: @PrabhatJha that sounds liked closed values to me. Still, there's only two reasons why some values would be missing: they're not in the Support Process, or they're closed status values and you're not on a close screen and you don't have the allow close-on-edit feature enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everyone for your answers.what i did to solve this:i created a new support process with existing suport process as master for this.and edited the recordtype with these newly created supported process and it worked!! –

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I simply assigned my record type to a different support process, refreshed and then changed them back. That worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check two things

1) your status picklist values are not deactivated
2) your picklist values are added to the support process the record type is linked to.

if the above two are correct then picklist values should display on your case.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers.what i did to solve this:i created a new support process with existing suport process as master for this.and edited the recordtype with these newly created supported process and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Please navigate to Setup - Cases - Support Settings - Edit  and check the "Show Closed Statuses in Case Status Field"